# Marker animation creates duplicates

Tags: android, animation, google-maps-markers

I develop a location-aware app and use a custom marker as MyLocation (`'blue-dot'`) but whenever the marker moves to a new Location it leaves a duplicate at the old Position on the map.

Here the Code:

Marker

```
myMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .flat(true)
                .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
                .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                .visible(true)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.position)));
```

Call

```
if (calcDistance(mCurrentLocation, reference) > 0.1) //prevent wobbly marker
{
   animateMarker(myMarker, mCurrentLocation);
}
```

Method

```
static void animateMarker(final Marker marker, final LatLng finalPosition) {
            TypeEvaluator<LatLng> typeEvaluator = new TypeEvaluator<LatLng>() {
                @Override
                public LatLng evaluate(float fraction, LatLng startValue, LatLng endValue) {
                    double lat = (finalPosition.latitude - marker.getPosition().latitude) * fraction + marker.getPosition().latitude;
                    double lng = (finalPosition.longitude - marker.getPosition().longitude) * fraction + marker.getPosition().longitude;
                    return new LatLng(lat, lng);
                }
            };
            Property<Marker, LatLng> property = Property.of(Marker.class, LatLng.class, "position");
            ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(marker, property, typeEvaluator, finalPosition);
            animator.setDuration(3000);
            animator.start();
        }
```

As you may notice the animateMarker-Method is from a GoogleDevBytes Video, so I guess that shouldn't be the Problem

Am I doing something wrong? Is it a bug in googles Api?

Answer (score 0):

Check this gist: https://gist.github.com/broady/6314689
Try implemting it that way

Answer (score 0):

Change below:

```
if (calcDistance(mCurrentLocation, reference) > 0.1) //prevent wobbly marker
{
   animateMarker(myMarker, mCurrentLocation);
}
```

To this:

```
if (calcDistance(mCurrentLocation, reference) > 0.1) //prevent wobbly marker
{
   if (myMarker != null) {
       myMarker.remove(); 
   }
   animateMarker(myMarker, mCurrentLocation);
}
```